# Removing files from history (out of disk space)

Tags: svn, centos, svnadmin

It appears that our server hosting our svn is full. Is there any way to remove larger files from the repo history? The research I've done was to run svnadmin dump, pipe it to the dumpfilter and load it into a new repo. The problem with this is that we don't have enough diskspace for the dump file. I know it's horrid. We only have 230 revisions, and we really only need maybe the last 50 or so. If there's some back door way of getting this done that won't completely muck up the repo - I'm all ears.

Comment: lol. 230 revisions and out of space already? What do you store in the repository?

Comment: @bahrep: Kittens. 230 kittens. All doing the darndest things.

Comment: @bahrep: tell me about it. mostly .fla (flash) files and audio files. Unfortunately we work with some remote people so having the necessary assets on the server is, well, necessary. I'm sure there's a better way / place to put those files, but it was a quick solution at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up removing some stuff from the server since it wasn't just an svn server, running a dump for the head revision, deleting everything, and loading the dump file. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Move the repo to a new server with more space. In the age of virtual machines and cloud-based servers, it should be the fastest approach.

Comment: I agree with you. However, if that were an option I wouldn't have posted (I don't mean to sound snarky). :)